# Convert sound to byte array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some ideas/pointer on how to convert sound(.amr/.wmv) files to byte array using only javascript

Please advice

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see this blog post to understand the [JS File Reader API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). Basically you want to use the readAsArrayBuffer() of JS File Reader API to read the file and get back a byte array.